# Alternative to store a value in memory during application lifecycle

Tags: performance, android-activity, android

I have an application that gets location information from the user, and that spends battery, it's totally undesirable to make frequent requests for location as the app only needs 1 time unless the user manually refresh.

So the problem is, i noticed that sometimes the value is null even if i store it in onSave and restore it in onCreate, so the garbage collector is doing it's job (app uses bitmap allocation, orientation changes may occur also, so i think this isn't strange), and now i'm thinking on subclassing the application to keep a global reference to the location var, but several people is against this (mostly against static vars) so i wonder if is there any alternative. Storing values in SharedPreferences doesn't seem like a good/clean/fast option to me, disk even less as the location wouldn't be important if the app is destroyed, it only matters as long as the app is running and to avoid the garbage collector.

Thanks

Saving the value

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("mCurrentLocation", mCurrentLocation);
    ...
}
```

Restoring the value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("mCurrentLocation");
        ...
    }
...
```

Error:

```
    Location location = ((mainActivity) mActivity).location;
    userLongitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()); //null sometimes!, not always
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong in your `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. It should be easily possible to store and retrieve location data in there. After all, it's only a few bytes. You are either not inserting it into the bundle properly, or not getting it out again properly.

You certainly don't need to put it in SharedPreferences, unless you want it to survive between invocations of the app. And for location data, that's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: added my ways to save and restore plus the error that happens _sometimes_

Comment: @Motheus Have you tried checking in `onSaveInstanceState` that the location you're putting in is always non-null? And checking whether the restored `mCurrentLocation` is null?

Comment: After the location is received it should never be null because this is a requirement for some functions, also it won't be modified again after obtained. It's a requirement to run, so it's impossible at this point the location was null from the code or never retrieved. That's why i guessed that the Garbage Collector was taking it before/after onSave so that piece of code wouldn't reach it _sometimes_